# using post_type with meta_query

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, meta-query

I'm setting up a basic slideshow and want to loop through the custom post type “Projects” and display *only* projects with a photo attached -

```
<ul class="slides">
        <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'meta_query' => array('key' => 'homepage_slide','value' => 'true'));
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <li>  
            <img src="<?php the_field('homepage_slide'); ?>" alt="slide" /></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>          
    </ul>
```

Unfortunately this code is trying to include slides for *all* projects. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`meta_query` allows you to specify multiple meta conditions, so should be an array of arrays:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'homepage_slide',
            'value' => 'true'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't work. And as the field is calling an image, I don't think value=true is going to work either. I've been advised that compare is what I need, but that still doesn't work - 

`$args = array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'meta_query' => array('key' => 'homepage_slide', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'));`